# Error serializing .staticPosts[0].data.postedOn returned from getStaticProps in "/"

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, server-side-rendering

```
import Banner from "../components/Banner";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import PostCard from "../components/PostCard";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { MediumContext } from "../context/MediumContext";
import { db, auth, provider } from "../firebase";
import { collection, getDocs, setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function Home({ staticPosts }) {
  const { postss, users } = useContext(MediumContext);
  const posts = staticPosts;
  // console.log(posts);
  // console.log(postss,"context")

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Banner />
      <div className=" flex flex-col sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
        {!posts ? (
          <div>Loading</div>
        ) : (
          posts.map((post) => {
            return <PostCard post={post} key={post.id} />;
          })
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "articles"));
  const staticPosts = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    return {
      id: doc.id,
      data: {
        author: doc.data().author,
        body: doc.data().body,
        brief: doc.data().brief,
        category: doc.data().category,
        postLength: doc.data().postLength,
        title: doc.data().title,
        postedOn: doc.data().postedOn.toDate(),
        bannerImage: doc.data().bannerImage,
      },
    };
  });

  return {
    props: {
      staticPosts,
    },
  };
}
```

hey when i am trying this **getStaticProps in nextjs** it is showing me this error, previously i tried with **useEffect() hook** it worked fine , can anyone help he how to resolve this

Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.staticPosts[0].data.postedOn` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
Reason: `object` ("[object Date]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

hey i found this someWhere on google and tried , it works fine , making changes in **return statement of getStaticPaths()**

JSON.stringify() -- > this is used to convert object to string

JSON.parse() --> this is used to convert string to object

```
  return {
    props: {
      staticPosts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(staticPosts)),
    },
  };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).